# Plugin options page: grouping checkboxes

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I've been using the **WordPress Option Page Generator** by *Jeremy Hixon* to help give me a head start with my plugin's option page. I've laid out four different types of checkboxes which the source code can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/factmaven/3896a3aac3888aa5bcddae48d9da5238

However, I'd like to add additional checkboxes in each of the four section that I've made, like so:

[image: Expected result: grouping checkboxes into sections]

Based on the generator, it looks like I would need to add another `add_settings_field` and another callback function to add more checkboxes; but that looks more tedious than I'd imagine just to add more checkboxes under each section. Is it possible to add additional checkboxes underneath the `add_settings_field` that I've already created? For example:

```
public function personal_options_0_callback() {
    printf(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="profile_settings_option_name[personal_options_0]" id="personal_options_0" value="personal_options_0" %s> <label for="personal_options_0"> Visual Editor</label>',
        ( isset( $this->profile_settings_options['personal_options_0'] ) && $this->profile_settings_options['personal_options_0'] === 'personal_options_0' ) ? 'checked' : ''
    );
    printf(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="profile_settings_option_name[personal_options_1]" id="personal_options_1" value="personal_options_1" %s> <label for="personal_options_1"> Admin Color Scheme</label>',
        ( isset( $this->profile_settings_options['personal_options_1'] ) && $this->profile_settings_options['personal_options_1'] === 'personal_options_1' ) ? 'checked' : ''
    );
}
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. I've never made a plugin options page before, so if there is a simpler way of doing this, I am also open to your recommendation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the [WordPress Support Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-options-page-grouping-checkboxes), in some instances, it's easier to develop an array which stores the value value.

To group the checkboxes, I simply copied the same format from the **Discussion** settings page to get my expected result: *a group of checkboxes that are formatted using WordPress' native style*. Here's a good template to work off of:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Profile Settings</h1>

    <form method="post" action="action_here">
        <table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Personal Options</th>
                    <td>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Personal Options</span></legend>
                            <label for="rich_editing">
                            <input name="rich_editing" type="checkbox" value="rich_editing" />
                            Visual Editor</label>
                            <br>
                            <label for="admin_color">
                            <input name="admin_color" type="checkbox" value="admin_color" />
                            Admin Color Scheme</label>
                            <br>
                            <label for="comment_shortcuts">
                            <input name="comment_shortcuts" type="checkbox" value="comment_shortcuts" />
                            Keyboard Shortcuts</label>
                            <br>
                            <label for="admin_bar_front">
                            <input name="admin_bar_front" type="checkbox" value="admin_bar_front" />
                            Toolbar</label>
                            <br>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Name</th>
                    <td>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Name</span></legend>
                            <label for="first_name">
                            <input name="first_name" type="checkbox" value="first_name" />
                            First Name</label>
                            <br>
                            <label for="last_name">
                            <input name="last_name" type="checkbox" value="last_name" />
                            Last Name</label>
                            <br>
                            <label for="nickname">
                            <input name="nickname" type="checkbox" value="nickname" />
                            Nickname</label>
                            <br>
                            <label for="display_name">
                            <input name="display_name" type="checkbox" value="display_name" />
                            Display Name</label>
                            <br>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### Result

[image]